# collision object outside mesh o cloth sim when rendering

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

I've tried following a 'default cube' tutorial on Youtube. which is a glowing sphere inside a cube that has a cloth sim on it. I've used the same settings. When viewing it in the viewports the spare collides with the cloth object moving it around. But when I try to render it, as a still frame or animation, parts of the cloth disappear and the sphere is outside this mesh. I have tried it also with a default principled BSDF incase the transparent shader was causing the issue, but the effect is the same

here's a link to the tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsTkoyRaKO0&t=395s

and a google drive link to the blend file and a screen shot showing the difference between the rendered image and the viewport.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OChKIjC1lzAon5RYcRwYW_L9DB-OXJV0?usp=sharing

I am using the latest 'official' release o blender (not a beta or alpha) and I'm running it on a mid 2015 iMac with Big Sur OS

Hope someone can help

Best Wishes

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Bake the physics. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search `bake all physics`.

[image]

Or look for baking in cache settings of cloth physics.

With physics baked, you should have no problems

Comment: Hi thank you for replying.
I have tried baking the physics but I am still having the same issue